# PyTorch PPO implementation for Cartpole-v0 getting stuck in local optima

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, policy-gradient-descent

I have implemented PPO for Cartpole-VO environment. However, it does not converge in certain iterations of the game. Sometimes it gets stuck in local optima. I have implemented the algorithm using the TD-0 advantage i.e.

`A(s_t) = R(t+1) + \gamma V(S_{t+1}) - V(S_t)`

Here is my code:

```
def running_average(x, n):
    N = n
    kernel = np.ones(N)
    conv_len = x.shape[0]-N
    y = np.zeros(conv_len)
    for i in range(conv_len):
        y[i] = kernel @ x[i:i+N] # matrix multiplication operator: np.mul
        y[i] /= N
    return y



class ActorNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, state_dim, n_actions, learning_rate=0.0003, epsilon_clipping=0.3, update_epochs=10):
        super().__init__()
        self.n_actions = n_actions
        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(state_dim, 64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(64, 32),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(32, n_actions),
            nn.Softmax(dim=-1)
        ).float()
        self.optimizer = optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
        self.epsilon_clipping = epsilon_clipping
        self.update_epochs = update_epochs

    def forward(self, X):
        return self.model(X)

    
    def predict(self, state):
        if state.ndim < 2:
            action_probs = self.model(torch.FloatTensor(state).unsqueeze(0).float())
        else: 
            action_probs = self.model(torch.FloatTensor(state))

        return action_probs.squeeze(0).data.numpy()

   
    def update(self, states, actions, deltas, old_prob):
  
        batch_size = len(states)
        state_batch = torch.Tensor(states)
        action_batch = torch.Tensor(actions)
        delta_batch = torch.Tensor(deltas)
        old_prob_batch = torch.Tensor(old_prob)
        for k in range(self.update_epochs):
            pred_batch = self.model(state_batch)

            prob_batch = pred_batch.gather(dim=1, index=action_batch.long().view(-1, 1)).squeeze()

            ratio = torch.exp(torch.log(prob_batch) - torch.log(old_prob_batch))

            clipped = torch.clamp(ratio, 1 - self.epsilon_clipping, 1 + self.epsilon_clipping) * delta_batch
            loss_r = -torch.min(ratio*delta_batch, clipped)
            loss = torch.mean(loss_r)
            self.optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            self.optimizer.step()




class CriticNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, state_dim, learning_rate=0.001):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(state_dim, 64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(64, 32),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(32, 1),
        ).float()
        self.optimizer = optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)


    def forward(self, X):
        return self.model(X)

    def predict(self, state):
        if state.ndim < 2:
            values = self.model(torch.FloatTensor(state).unsqueeze(0).float())
        else:
            values = self.model(torch.FloatTensor(state))

        return values.data.numpy()

  
    def update(self, states, targets):
        
        state_batch = torch.Tensor(states)
        target_batch = torch.Tensor(targets)
        pred_batch = self.model(state_batch)
        loss = torch.nn.functional.mse_loss(pred_batch, target_batch.unsqueeze(1))
        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        self.optimizer.step()

    


def train_ppo_agent(env, episode_length, max_episodes, gamma, visualize_step, learning_rate_actor=0.0003, learning_rate_critic=0.001, epsilon_clipping=0.2, actor_update_epochs=10):

  
    model_actor = ActorNetwork(env.observation_space.shape[0], env.action_space.n, learning_rate=learning_rate_actor,
                               epsilon_clipping=epsilon_clipping, update_epochs=actor_update_epochs)
    model_critic = CriticNetwork(env.observation_space.shape[0], learning_rate=learning_rate_critic)



    EPISODE_LENGTH = episode_length
    MAX_EPISODES = max_episodes
    GAMMA = gamma
    VISUALIZE_STEP = max(1, visualize_step)
    score = []


    for episode in range(MAX_EPISODES):
        curr_state = env.reset()
        done = False
        all_episode_t = []
        score_episode = 0
        for t in range(EPISODE_LENGTH):
            act_prob = model_actor.predict(curr_state)
            action = np.random.choice(np.array(list(range(env.action_space.n))), p=act_prob)
            value = model_critic.predict(curr_state)
            prev_state = curr_state
            curr_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
            score_episode += reward
            e_t = {'state': prev_state, 'action':action, 'action_prob':act_prob[action],'reward': reward, 'value': value}
            all_episode_t.append(e_t)
            if done:
                break
        score.append(score_episode)

        episode_values = [all_episode_t[t]['value'] for t in range(len(all_episode_t))]
        next_state_estimates = [episode_values[i].item() for i in range(1, len(episode_values))]
        next_state_estimates.append(0)
        boostrap_estimate = []
        for t in range(len(all_episode_t)):
            G = all_episode_t[t]['reward'] + GAMMA * next_state_estimates[t]
            boostrap_estimate.append(G)

        episode_target = np.array(boostrap_estimate)
        episode_values = np.array(episode_values)
        # compute the advantage for each state in the episode: R_{t+1} + \gamma * V(S_{t+1}) - V_{t}
        adv_batch = episode_target-episode_values
       
        state_batch = np.array([all_episode_t[t]['state'] for t in range(len(all_episode_t))])
        action_batch = np.array([all_episode_t[t]['action'] for t in range(len(all_episode_t))])
        old_actor_prob = np.array([all_episode_t[t]['action_prob'] for t in range(len(all_episode_t))])
       
        model_actor.update(state_batch, action_batch, adv_batch, old_actor_prob)
       
        model_critic.update(state_batch, episode_target)

        # print the status after every VISUALIZE_STEP episodes
        if episode % VISUALIZE_STEP == 0 and episode > 0:
            print('Episode {}\tAverage Score: {:.2f}'.format(episode, np.mean(score[-VISUALIZE_STEP:-1])))
            # domain knowledge applied to stop training: if the average score across last 100 episodes is greater than 195, game is solved
            if np.mean(score[-100:-1]) > 195:
                break


    # Training plot: Episodic reward over Training Episodes
    score = np.array(score)
    avg_score = running_average(score, visualize_step)
    plt.figure(figsize=(15, 7))
    plt.ylabel("Episodic Reward", fontsize=12)
    plt.xlabel("Training Episodes", fontsize=12)
    plt.plot(score, color='gray', linewidth=1)
    plt.plot(avg_score, color='blue', linewidth=3)
    plt.scatter(np.arange(score.shape[0]), score, color='green', linewidth=0.3)
    plt.savefig("temp/cartpole_ppo_training_plot.pdf")

    # return the trained models
    return model_actor, model_critic

def main():
    env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
    episode_length = 300
    n_episodes = 5000
    gamma = 0.99
    vis_steps = 100
    learning_rate_actor = 0.0003
    actor_update_epochs = 10
    epsilon_clipping = 0.2
    learning_rate_critic = 0.001
   
    # train the PPO agent
    model_actor, model_critic = train_ppo_agent(env, episode_length, n_episodes, gamma, vis_steps,
                                               learning_rate_actor=learning_rate_actor,
                                               learning_rate_critic=learning_rate_critic,
                                               epsilon_clipping=epsilon_clipping,
                                               actor_update_epochs=actor_update_epochs)
```

Am I missing something, or is this kind of behaviour expected if one uses simple TD-0 advantages for PPO, given the nature of the Cartpole environment?

Comment: Honestly it's just that TD(0) sucks. Try GAE Advantages or 16 Step Return.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the "-" (the negative marker) in line:

```
loss_r = -torch.min(ratio*delta_batch, clipped)
```

The score will then start to steadily increase over time. Before this fix you had negative loss which would increase over time. This is not how loss should work for neural networks. As gradient descent works to minimize the loss. So you want a positive loss which can be minimized by optimizer.

Hope my answer is somewhat clear, and sorry I cannot go into deeper detail.

My run can be seen in the attached image:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, the PPO objective is to increase the objective function (referred to as 'loss_r') via gradient ascent. Hence, the negative sign was added, so that the standard optimization procedure like gradient descent can be applied to negative of loss_r = gradient ascent on positive loss_r.

Comment: @204 I’m facing the same issue using PPO and cartpole, did you solve it?